# Array dimensions of element by element array operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

aa is an n by 1 array (aa.shape yields (n,1)). bb is an n array (bb.shape yeilds (n,)). cc = aa - bb. cc is an n by n array (cc.shape yields (n,n). cc should be n by 1 at most. Is this how numpy is supposed to work? Is it a bug? It's difficult to avoid getting an n by nothing array.

Comment: `(n,)` is a n-element 1d array, not a `n by nothing` (read up on Python tuples).  By `numpy` broadcasting rules a (n,1) + (n,) => (n,1)+(1,n)=>(n,n)`.  Read up on `numpy` broadcasting.

Comment: Thanks. I understand and will read up on tuples and numpy broadcasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the MRE you posted in the comment, reformatted:

```py
>>> aa=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
>>> bb=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> aa - bb
array([[ 1, 0, -1, -2], [ 2, 1, 0, -1], [ 3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

What are you trying to do here? the problem is that numpy interprets each nested string as a new dimension, so `aa` has 4 rows and 1 column, while `bb` has 1 row.  When you subtract them, numpy interprets it as subtracting each value in `bb` from each row in `aa`.  this means that the result will have as many rows as `aa`, with the value of each column being the difference between that row of `aa` with the corresponding value of `bb`.

if you just want to subtract them as two 1-dimensional vectors, then you need to initialize `aa` differently or use the `flatten` method:

```py
>>> aa=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
>>> bb=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> aa = aa.flatten()
>>> aa - bb
array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: aa=np.array([[2],[3],[4]])
bb=np.array([1,2,3,4])
aa - bb

Out[21]: 
array([[ 1,  0, -1, -2],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  0]])

Comment: Sorry, the formatting didn't turn out as I intended.

Comment: The problem seems to stem from the different dimensions of the two arrays. I finally resolved the problem by aa = np.concatenate(aa)  then aa-bb but it seems this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I think that explains it!